# php mysql query for top 5 average of columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of rankings for photos.  I’d like to output the id of the top 5 photos for each category based on the average of 3 columns (rating1, 2, 3).

Say I have the following table columns (photoID,rating1,rating2,rating3)

```
 $sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes ORDER BY AVG(rating1) ASC LIMIT 5") or   die(mysql_error()); 

 $rows = array();
 while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
 $rows[] = $r;
 }
 echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Where are the categories in your table?

Comment: rating1, rating2, rating3 are the categories.  Each row represents a voter.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rating1+rating2+rating3 AS total FROM `test` ORDER BY total  DESC
```

this?

Answer (score 0):

Records in MySql are already returned in Ascending order by default, but you likely want to use the `DESC` keyword, not `ASC`. Why are you averaging the `ratings1` column, if you're trying to select the top 5??

Reread the question, resubmitting a new answer.

```
$sth = "SELECT * FROM pics ORDER BY (rating1 + rating2 + rating3) desc LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: there may be 10 ratings for each photo, I’d like to find the highest 5 for a rating using the average of all 10 ratings.    Say I have the following data  photoID 1  rating1 4; photoID 1 rating1 1; photoID 2 rating1 10; photoID 2 rating1 8.  I’d like the output to be photoID 2 then photoID 1 (i.e. average rating 1 is 9 and 2.5 respectively)

Answer (score 0):

The way you explained your question was unclear, this might be what you want:

```
SELECT photoID, AVG((rating1+rating2+rating3)/3) as rating
FROM votes GROUP BY photoID ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 1            AS category
         , photoID
         , AVG(rating1) AS avg_rating
    FROM votes 
    GROUP BY photoID
    ORDER BY avg_rating DESC 
    LIMIT 5

  UNION ALL

    SELECT 2            AS category
         , photoID
         , AVG(rating2) AS avg_rating
    FROM votes 
    GROUP BY photoID
    ORDER BY avg_rating DESC 
    LIMIT 5

  UNION ALL

    SELECT 3            AS category
         , photoID
         , AVG(rating3) AS avg_rating
    FROM votes 
    GROUP BY photoID
    ORDER BY avg_rating DESC 
    LIMIT 5
```